# how to make accordion menu using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt6

I want to create an accordion menu with the help of qt designer. anyone know how to do it? thanks

[image: something like this]

Comment: Are you using pyqt?

Comment: A simple search for qt accordion will give you the answer

Comment: @martineau yes, I'm using pyqt6 ..

Comment: @David yes, I am yes, I've done a simple search via google, but I haven't found it.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/60408/accordion-widget-for-qt5. This is the first result on Google for qt accordion

Comment: @David oh it really helped me, thanks David. have a nice day :)